# how to add data from react component using onsubmit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add data from component, this is my component which functions to input data

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { addNote } from "../../utils/local-data";
const InputNote = () => {
    const [note, setNote] = useState({
        title: "",
        body: "",
    });

    const changeHandler = (event) => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        setNote((prevValue) => ({
            ...prevValue,
            [name]: value,
        }));
    };

    const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        return addNote(note.title, note.body);
    };

    return (
        <section className="input__catatan">
            <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                <input
                    name="title"
                    value={note.title}
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Tambahkan catatan"
                    onChange={changeHandler}
                />
                <textarea
                    name="body"
                    value={note.body}
                    placeholder="Catat sesuatu"
                    cols="30"
                    rows="10"
                    onChange={changeHandler}
                ></textarea>
                <input
                    type="submit"
                    className="submit"
                    value="Submit"
                />
            </form>
        </section>
    );
};

export default InputNote;
```

this is my local-data and function to add data is here.

```
let notes = [
    {
        id: "notes-1",
        title: "Babel",
        body: "Babel merupakan tools open-source yang digunakan untuk mengubah sintaks ECMAScript 2015+ menjadi sintaks yang didukung oleh JavaScript engine versi lama. Babel sering dipakai ketika kita menggunakan sintaks terbaru termasuk sintaks JSX.",
        createdAt: "2022-04-14T04:27:34.572Z",
        archived: false,
    },
];


function addNote({ title, body }) {
    notes = [
        ...notes,
        {
            id: `notes-${+new Date()}`,
            title: title || "(untitled)",
            body,
            createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
            archived: false,
        },
    ];
}
```

I think the local-data function is correct, maybe the problem is in the components but I'm still confused where the error is.
When the code is run the data can't be input I don't know what the problem is

Comment: The `addNote` function is not mutating the state in your component, but its own local variable in a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the function addNotes used the object {node.title, node.body} as param, but got addNotes(node.title, node,body) as two separate inputs. This caused the values to be undefined and therefore all entries had untitled as title and body undefined. By adding this we can see that the values was indeed updated

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

let initNotes = [
  {
    id: "notes-1",
    title: "Babel",
    body: "Babel merupakan tools open-source yang digunakan untuk mengubah sintaks ECMAScript 2015+ menjadi sintaks yang didukung oleh JavaScript engine versi lama. Babel sering dipakai ketika kita menggunakan sintaks terbaru termasuk sintaks JSX.",
    createdAt: "2022-04-14T04:27:34.572Z",
    archived: false,
  },
];

const InputNote = () => {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState(initNotes);
  const [note, setNote] = useState({
    title: "",
    body: "",
  });

  function addNote({title, body}) {
    const newNotes = [
      ...notes,
      {
        id: `notes-${+new Date()}`,
        title: title ?? "(untitled)",
        body,
        createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
        archived: false,
      },
    ];
    setNotes(newNotes);
  }

  const changeHandler = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setNote((prevValue) => ({
      ...prevValue,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addNote(note.title, note.body);
  };

  return (
    <section className="input__catatan">
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <input
          name="title"
          value={note.title}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Tambahkan catatan"
          onChange={changeHandler}
        />
        <textarea
          name="body"
          value={note.body}
          placeholder="Catat sesuatu"
          cols="30"
          rows="10"
          onChange={changeHandler}
        ></textarea>
        <input type="submit" className="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
      {notes.map((note) => (
        <li key={note.id}>{note.title}-{note.body}</li>
      ))}
    </section>
  );
};

export default InputNote;
```